# Custom Pages with STRI Modules?

Tags: dxa

I understand we can make SDL Tridion Reference Implementation (STRI) Modules which include Content Manager and Delivery-side functionality.

- Should new Modules include a PowerShell script for installation?
- Are things like Custom Pages or even GUI Extensions allowed for Modules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A module is just a package of your additional features or functionality. I'd say it is nice if it comes with a powershell script to install (or any other form of a installer), but if you add a `readme.txt` or `install.txt` with it, that could also be sufficient.

While a Module is a concept on the CM through creating a Folder under `\Building Blocks\Modules` and similair in the web application through a folder under `\Areas`, it really isn't anything else than what we make it. So if you have a UI extension that adds functionality then there isn't really anything stopping you from packinging it up as an installable entity and call it a Module.